# How to send SQS message asynchronously in python?

Tags: python, node.js, amazon-web-services, asynchronous, amazon-sqs

Here's my Python code right now:

```
sqs = boto3.resource('sqs')
queue = sqs.get_queue_by_name(Queue='test')
msg = 'hello world'
for i in range(0,1000):
    queue.send_message(MessageBody = msg)
    print("Message Sent")
```

And here is the Node.js version:

```
var sqs = new AWS.SQS({apiVersion: '2012-11-05'});
var params = {
    MessageBody: 'hello world',
    QueueUrl: // Queue URL here
};
for(var i = 0; i < 1000; i++){
    sqs.sendMessage(params, function(err,data){
        if(err){
            throw err;
        } else {
            console.log("Message Sent");
        }
    })
}
```

My problem is that it takes significantly longer to send 1000 messages using the Python script because it runs synchronously vs Node.js doing it asynchronously. I've looked everywhere and I can't seem to find any way to send messages asynchronously in Python. Insight would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

The boto3 library does not support async calls. There is a library that supports S3 with some testing on SQS called aiobotocore. These links have more information:

[aiobotocore](https://github.com/aio-libs/aiobotocore)

[Support asyncio](https://github.com/boto/botocore/issues/458)

Comment: Thank you. I will look into these.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to suggest my own Python package for this: it uses just aiohttp and lxml, without any boto-dependencies. https://github.com/d3QUone/aiosqs

Comment: Boto3 sqs does not require `aws_access_key_id` and `aws_secret_access_key` when running from lambda - is it necessary with your package?

Comment: boto3 uses same variables, but they may be in your env variables. Or it may use aws_token. In current stage the package supports only aws_access_key_id + aws_secret_access_key authorisation.